# Antlr Base Visitor not being created

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4

After writing a grammar in g4 and putting it into my Output Folder, there is no BaseVisitor File created after compiling with ANTLR, which i need.
I am running `java org.antlr.v4.Tool -o -visitor -listener -o "Output Directory" -Dlanguage=CSharp "Input File.g4"` in the command line, and only the files on the image are being created.

i already tried upgrading ANTLR, but that gave no solution (https://i.stack.imgur.com/8O9LM.png)

Answer (score 0):

ive resolved it, i dont see why there was a "-o" before "-visitor"